# Assemble (templates): Get parent value from within nested each block

Tags: html, handlebars.js, assemble, grunt-assemble

I have a problem getting a value from a parent loop/each. How can I do this?

I'm looping through some questions, and then loop through some answers. On each answer I would like to add the question ID..

**The JSON:**

```
{
    "questions": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "answers": [
                ...
                ...
                ...
            ]
        }
    ]

}
```

**And the Assemble.io nested loops/each**

```
{{#forEach questions}}
    <h2>{{id}}</h2>
    <ul>
        {{#forEach this.answers}}
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="{{id}}" id="{{id}}-{{index}}"/>
            </li>
        {{/forEach}}
    </ul>
{{/forEach}}
```

Do you know how I can get the ID from the parent loop/each?

Thank you in advance... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In handlebars, you can use the [parent accessor syntax `../`](http://handlebarsjs.com/#paths)

```
{{#forEach questions}}
    <h2>{{id}}</h2>
    <ul>
        {{#forEach this.answers}}
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="{{../id}}" id="{{../id}}-{{index}}"/>
            </li>
        {{/forEach}}
    </ul>
{{/forEach}}
```

Comment: Great! Can't believe I didn't find that. Thank you!